# Is orthogonal initialization still useful when hidden layer sizes vary?

Tags: deep-neural-networks, computational-learning-theory, weights-initialization, linear-algebra

[Pytorch's orthogonal initialization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.orthogonal_) cites ["Exact solutions to the nonlinear dynamics of learning in deep linear neural networks
", Saxe, A. et al. (2013)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6120), which gives as reason for the usefulness of orthogonal initialization the fact that for a linear multi-layer network, the singular values of the product of all weight matrices are "isometric" i.e. all close to 1.

However, I can empirically see that if I use this initialization method for hidden layers that have a higher number of neurons than the input and output, then isometry goes away. E.g.

```
import torch, numpy
def g(r,c):
    w = torch.empty(r, c)
    return torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(w).numpy()
numpy.linalg.svd(g(5,7)@g(7,5))[1]
# Out[1]: 
# array([1.0000001 , 1.        , 0.99999994, 0.7571472 , 0.05615549],
#      dtype=float32)
```

My question: is orthogonal initialization still useful when hidden layer sizes vary? Should I be doing some additional things when dealing with such variations?